# How to show a menu depending on what is selected?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jlist, jmenuitem

In swing, how do i show a menu depending on what was selected from another menu.

For example: Select Country drop down. This is followed by a State drop down, followed by city.

When a particular Country is selected, then show the states for that country. Also, when a state is selected, show the cities in the state.

Comment: Listen to the selection event, display the corresponding menu?

Comment: Move mouse round something is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JMenu` can contain `JMenuItem` & `JMenu` instances.  You might have it so that the main menu contains menus for countries.  Each country menu has menus for states, then each state has menu *items* for city.

OTOH a nicer user experience would be provided by 3 `JComboBox` instances.  The first is for the country, the 2nd and third are populated as needed (on demand).

Comment: @trashgod  +1 for the link to example.  I've already up-voted that answer, so I'll have settle for a +1 on the comment. :)